# Write date to SQL using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, date

Till today I used this function to write dates from my access form to SQL server. Today I noticed that now() function is not working anymore. I tried date() - still not working. Getdate cannot use in VBA. I need to have exact date with minutes. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

```
CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE CI SET D_Date = now() WHERE ID = " & Id & ";"), dbSeeChanges
```

Comment: Have you checked for missing references?

Comment: How about using the SQL server function `GETDATE()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenation of Variables/Constants in VBA is usually performed by using the Ampersand operator. However, there a few variations depending on the data types.

If the field for which the value supplied is String they need to be enclosed within, the String literal (single or double quotes).

```
Dim myName As String
myName = "Paul"
strSQL = "UPDATE tableName SET TextFieldName = '" & myName & "'"
```

The above is not always safe, errors happen when using names with a single quotes in them. So, this is always a better way.

```
Dim myName As String
myName = "Paul O'Connor"
strSQL = "UPDATE tableName SET TextFieldName = " & Chr(34) & myName & Chr(34)
```

For Dates, they need to be enclosed in between #,

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tableName SET DateFieldName = #" & Date() & "#"
```

It is only numeric values that need no specific enclosures.

```
Dim myNumber As Long
myNumber = 55
strSQL = "UPDATE tableName SET NumberFieldName = " & myNumber
```

So in your query it needs to be,

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE CI SET D_Date = #" & Now() & "# WHERE ID = " & Id, dbSeeChanges
```